# Location Specific Sell

Tags: magento-1.9, sales, locations, area

I would not like to sell my product in below states of USA. Alaska
Hawaii, Porto Rico, po box, Military bases, APO.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento gives users the ability to restrict shipping to certain countries under specific shipping methods. However, the is no native functionality for restricting shipping to certain states within countries.

You can use this [extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/12349/s/remove-or-change-displayed-states-and-regions-1964/) to sell specific location.

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Helper/Data.php**

rewrite the helper or copy this **local/** folder

add filter in `_getRegions`

```
protected function _getRegions($storeId)
    {
        $countryIds = array();

        $countryCollection = $this->getCountryCollection()->loadByStore($storeId);
        foreach ($countryCollection as $country) {
            $countryIds[] = $country->getCountryId();
        }

        /** @var $regionModel Mage_Directory_Model_Region */
        $regionModel = $this->_factory->getModel('directory/region');
        /** @var $collection Mage_Directory_Model_Resource_Region_Collection */
        $regionarray=array('Alaska Hawaii', 'Alabama','Porto Rico', 'po box', 'Military bases');
        $collection = $regionModel->getResourceCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('name', array('nin' =>$array))
            ->addCountryFilter($countryIds)
            ->load();

        $regions = array(
            'config' => array(
                'show_all_regions' => $this->getShowNonRequiredState(),
                'regions_required' => $this->getCountriesWithStatesRequired()
            )
        );
        foreach ($collection as $region) {
            if (!$region->getRegionId()) {
                continue;
            }
            $regions[$region->getCountryId()][$region->getRegionId()] = array(
                'code' => $region->getCode(),
                'name' => $this->__($region->getName())
            );
        }
        return $regions;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Qaisar Satti. Your solution is working for **default package of athlete theme**. But it is not working for **254k package of default theme**.

Comment: you can check the method in `theme/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml` file this js code `var billingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', 'billing:region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'billing:postcode');`

Comment: @abuabu i not asking you adding this code. i am asking to check slimier code and which method they are using to get region may be other checkout ext they are using i can give solution on default other theme code are not available so i can guess on that.